# Giving functions alternate outputs

Tags: javascript, function, variables

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function dogName()
{
  var rand = alert("Clint.");
  var rand = alert("Bee.");
  var rand = alert("Copper.");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button"       value="RandName" onClick='dogName()'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code, function `dogName()` has three variables: `Clint`, `Bee`, and `Copper`. I want to make it where if you click the button `(RandName)` you get a random name chosen from the function listed above. I've searched everywhere for the answer but to no avail. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function dogName()
{
var rand = [ 'Clint', 'Bee', 'Copper' ];
alert(rand[Math.floor(Math.random()*rand.length)]);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button"       value="RandName" onClick='dogName()'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Create an array and pick one random element.

Answer (score 3):

First, your function has only one variable, `rand` which [will be `undefined`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yb001375/7/) as `alert()` does not `return` anything to the calling context.

To return a random name, however:

```
function dogName () {
    var names = ['clint','Bee','Copper'];
    return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)]
}

var name = dogName();

console.log(name);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yb001375/1/).

And a slightly updated demo, to show the output in an element (identified by it's `id`):

```
function dogName () {
    var names = ['Clint','Bee','Copper'],
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length),
        chosen = names[index];

    document.getElementById('output').value = chosen;
    return chosen;
}
```

Which works with the following HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="RandName" onClick='dogName(this)' />
    <label>The generated dog-name is: <input id="output" readonly="readonly" /></label>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yb001375/4/).

Further, it's usually considered best to avoid using event-handling attributes in the HTML (`onclick`, `onfocus`, `onchange` etc), the concept being 'unobtrusive JavaScript'; instead consider handling the event-binding in the JavaScript itself (that way it's all pretty much in the same place and makes for easier maintenance and change (this is usually inevitable at some point). That said, here's one approach that works in most modern browsers (including IE from version 9 onwards):

```
function dogName () {
    var names = ['Clint','Bee','Copper'],
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length),
        chosen = names[index];

    document.getElementById('output').value = chosen;
    return chosen;
}

var button = document.querySelector('input[value="RandName"]');

button.addEventListener('click', dogName);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yb001375/6/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute (`[attribute=value]`) selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).
  - [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).
  - [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Bibliography:

- "[The Principles of Ubobtrusive JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript)" (W3.org).
- "[Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)" (Wikipedia).

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a lot more than I asked for! I would upvote if I could.

Comment: May I ask why this answer was unaccepted? It's your prerogative, and entirely your right, to change the accepted answer, but I'd be interested to know where I fell short, in order that I might improve in future.

Comment: I think, @DavidThomas, that while your answer contains more information for Dingo, the other one was more direct answer to his question.